# OL6.3.1 : duplicate features displayed on a map

Tags: openlayers, wfs, duplication

Despite many posts read here, I can't find a solution to avoid duplicate features in my map.
The **url** is a WFS from Mapserver based on a PostGis view with an **unique** gid field.
All the geometries are unique as well.

```
import VectorSource from 'ol/source/Vector';
import VectorLayer from 'ol/layer/Vector';
import {GeoJSON} from 'ol/format';
import {bbox} from 'ol/loadingstrategy';
...
const prescriptionSource = new VectorSource({
    format: new GeoJSON(),
    loader: function(extent) {
      const url = 'http://.../Apache/site/mapfile/ol_prescription.map&' +
              'service=WFS&version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typename=prescription&outputFormat=geojson&SRSNAME=EPSG:3857&' + 
              'bbox=' + extent.join(',') + ',' + 'EPSG:3857'
        fetch(url)
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((data) => {
            const features = prescriptionSource.getFormat().readFeatures(data)
            // console.log(features)
            // features.forEach( feature => console.log(feature.values_.gid))
            prescriptionSource.addFeatures(features)
          })
    },//fin loader
    strategy: bbox,
  })

    const prescription = new VectorLayer({
    source: prescriptionSource,
     }
    });
```

Each time the map is moving, the same features stack on each other 2, 3 or 4 times.
The result is the same with an url function instead of a loader function.

Comment: A `gid` property is not the same as a feature id.  If you want that property to be the feature id you must set it before adding the features `features.forEach( feature => { feature.setId(feature.get('gid')); })`  Also avoid using internal properties ending with underscore as these can be minified in some builds.

Comment: that's it. Even if I have a warning message that says `Property 'setId' may not exist.`